# Application of machine learning in your job

Tags: machine-learning

For those of you who may implemented any machine learning application in your business context, can you share your experience and results obtained?

Amidst all the hype on AI I am interested to hear from actual applications.

Comment: Stack Exchange does not deal well with this kind of open question. Ideally you have a problem to solve and any single answer can address it in its entirety. This reads more like a poll where you need multiple different answers. A forum focused on machine learning might be a better place to post this question.

Answer (score 0):

Using machine-learning techniques, nowadays computers can automatically see and understand better than years ago. Tasks like recognition, localization, detection, semantic segmentation and related things have better performance today. This progress has promoted other fields too. Automatic cars, using autonomous driving benefit these advantages for pedestrian detection or car detection.

Recommender systems are so popular today. They suggest you exactly what you need based on your actions. On Facebook, you can find your old friends without even trying to. You can see a lot of movies which you may be sure that will like them.

During searching in search engines, you can see exactly what you are looking for without even knowing how the learning algorithm is ranking the results to show you the appropriate result.

Your email service finds spam and junk mails automatically and delete them for you and you can be confident that you won't loose any important thing.

OCR systems transform images of books and make them as text files. Using this, you can search in texts and find what you want without searching a lot of images.

Tasks which are difficult for finding algorithms, like walking of robots, are so better than before, using data and machine-learning.

There have been designed agents which can defeat human brain in famous games, like chess. Even in AAA computer games, the agents use reinforcement learning to learn how to defeat the human rivals using experience of each specific player based on their behavior.

Machine learning is EVERYWHERE.